# UnexpectedTypeException: HV000030: No validator could be found for constraint 'javax.validation.constraints.Size' validating type 'java.lang.String'

Tags: quarkus, hibernate-validator

I am getting this error when running integration tests for an endpoint in Quarkus. I make a POST request passing a valid object as body. Method signature:

```
 @POST
 public Response myMethodPost(@Valid MyObjData myObjData);
```

I get the following error:

```
javax.validation.UnexpectedTypeException: HV000030: No validator could be found for constraint 'javax.validation.constraints.Size' validating type 'java.lang.String'. Check configuration for 'myMethodPost.arg0.dataId'
```

Where `dataId` is a property of `MyObjData` of type `String`.
I have also included the following Maven dependencies:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-jsonb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: From your description I can't see any obvious error. We might need a reproducer project.

Answer (score 3):

Quarkus won't scan classes that are in other modules or jars, so it fails to register the validators at start up.

I had to add the [org.kordamp.gradle.jandex](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.kordamp.gradle.jandex) gradle plugin to my submodule in order for Quarkus to see the annations.

Discussion here: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/13233

Comment: A META-INF/beans.xml file works just as well and feels less intrusive than the plugin.